# PyTorch: How to parallelize over multiple GPU using multiprocessing.pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytorch, gpu

I have the following code which I am trying to parallelize over multiple GPUs in PyTorch:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool

X = np.array([[1, 3, 2, 3], [2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
X = torch.DoubleTensor(X).cuda()

def X_power_func(j):
    X_power = X**j
    return X_power

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Pool(processes = 2) as p:   # Parallelizing over 2 GPUs
    results = p.map(X_power_func, range(4))

results
```

But when I ran the code, I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "<ipython-input-35-6529ab6dac60>", line 11, in X_power_func
    X_power = X**j
RuntimeError: CUDA error: initialization error
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-6529ab6dac60> in <module>()
     14 if __name__ == '__main__':
     15   with Pool(processes = 1) as p:
---> 16     results = p.map(X_power_func, range(8))
     17 
     18 results

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    642             return self._value
    643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
    645 
    646     def _set(self, i, obj):

RuntimeError: CUDA error: initialization error
```

Where have I gone wrong? Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the usual approach is to call `model.share_memory()` once before multiprocessing, assuming you have a model which subclasses `nn.Module`.  For tensors, it should be `X.share_memory_()`.  Unfortunately, I had trouble getting that to work with your code, it hangs (without errors) if `X.share_memory_()` is called before calling pool.map; I'm not sure if the reason is because X is a global variable which is not passed as one of the arguments in map.

What does work is this:

```
X = torch.DoubleTensor(X)

def X_power_func(j):
    X_power = X.cuda()**j
    return X_power
```

Btw: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15734 mentions that "**CUDA API must not be initialized before you fork**" (this is likely the issue you were seeing).

Also https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17680 if using spawn in Jupyter notebooks "the spawn method will run everything in your notebook top-level" (likely the issue I was seeing when my code was hanging, in a notebook).  In short, I couldn't get either fork or spawn to work, *except* using the sequence above (which doesn't use CUDA until it's in the forked process).

Comment: Many thanks @Alex I. I tried calling `X.share_memory_()` after `if __name__ == '__main__'`:but I keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'share_memory'`. I can confirm using the sequence code you suggested above worked. The funny thing is that it only works when I run the code the first time. If I run it again, I get the error `RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method`.

Comment: I am using Google Colab and Kaggle Kernel and confirm with both, when I include `set_start_method('spawn', force=True)` after `if __name__ == '__main__':`, the code just hangs or keep running forever without any errors.

Comment: If you have any further insight on all these errors, please let me know. Many thanks once again.